# Dovecot  does not receive emails - Connection refused

Tags: email, domain-server, dovecot, mail-server

I try install Mail server on Ubuntu, I've installed dovecot server.

```
telnet localhost 110 - correct

telnet mail.domain.cz 110 - correct
```

When I send email:

```
echo "Testicek" | mail -s "Dovecot test" info@domain.cz
```

And connect to the box info@domain.cz, I found it, so it's correct.

But when I send email from outside (forexample Gmail), to info@domain.cz is returned:

```
The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. Learn more at http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=7720 [domain.cz (1): Connection refused]
```

In log isn't something error, so I don't know where I can find problem, but I think so, it can be in setting of domain:

```
   1800 A 31.31.73.***
 * 1800 A 31.31.73.***
```

Subdomains, etc. is correcly on apache (lamp) and send email via Squirrelmail is correct too.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

Port 110 is for POP3 which is only relevent for connecting to a POP3 server for downloading email.

For email to land on your server, you're talking about SMTP. This is what both your client and external relays use to move messages around the internet. SMTP uses port 25.

Dovecot has nothing to do with how emails land on your server. For this you need a Mail Transfer Agent like **`postfix`**. This is a SMTP server that will listen for external connections and route emails accordingly.

Install that from the command line (it'll walk you through some configuration options). You'll want to research the configuration because it can get a little complicated and you don't want to be an open relay (that is, you only want to accept email for your domains, and not forward on emails from spammers)

Comment: Yes, I have installed postfix. Maybe I found problem - when I try **telnet localhost 25**, it's correct, but from outside **telnet domain.com 25**, it's return **Connection refused**, but for **telnet domain.com 110** its correct too

Comment: Sounds like `postfix` or the firewall is the issue then. Assuming the firewall isn't an issue, you can reconfigure `postfix`  with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix`. Pick Internet site and make sure you specify the domains you want to handle email for.

Comment: Thanks, I make reconfigure, but it still dont work ;( Only from localhost `echo "Testicek" | mail -s "Next test" info@domain.cz`

Comment: I make **dpkg-reconfigure postfix** and now it works, but I think that setting is same - I don't know hot, but it works :) Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem: can receive mails and consult them only if they are sent from the same machine on which run the mail servers. I solved it by adding a MX record in the DNS which indicates that all emails@domain.cz should be routed to the mail server at domain.cz:

```
domain.cz. 14400 IN MX 0 domain.cz.
```